# Interface argument of TypeScript is not working when the code is transpiled

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, transpiler

I have a method inside a class named get()

```
import optionsInst from "./options";
get(url, opt: optionsInst){}
```

optionsInst is an interface of another file

```
export interface Options {
  tipoRespuesta?: "json" | "arrayBuffer";
  params?: string;
  data?: string;
  headers?: HeadersInit;
}
export default Options;
```

My tsconfig is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

To transpile i use `npm run build` and a dist folder is generated.
To test it, i create a new file and run `npm test.js`

```
var CL = require("../dist/index.js");

let instancia = new CL("https://reqres.in/api/");
instancia.get("users").then(console.log);
```

The error is like this:

```
  if (utils.isEmpty(opt.headers)) {
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

If the following line is inside the `get(url, opts: optionsInst)` method in the class

```
if (utils.isEmpty(opt.headers)) {
```

Then your problem is that you're calling it without the ops argument defined, here:

```
instancia.get("users").then(console.log);
```

The error is just saying that it can't read the property `opt.headers` because `opt` is `undefined`.

You should actually be getting a Typescript error for that line above, telling you that the `opts` argument is missing in the call - check that. But Typescript will still compile the code anyway, just resulting in a runtime error when you run it - obviously the very thing Typescript is trying to help you avoid!